# How to make jOOQ quote table names that are reserved keywords?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

On selecting from a table called `user` with jOOQ I get the following exception:

`jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [insert into user (user_id, account_type) values (?, ?)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"`

My jOOQ settings are:

```
private static final Settings jooqSettings = new Settings()
    .withRenderSchema(false)
    .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.LOWER);
```

I create a `DSLContext` from that and construct a query in a transaction as follows:

```
ctx.insertInto(USER)
      .set(USER.USER_ID, userId)
      .set(USER.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "U")
      .execute()
```

`USER` is imported as `<jooq-generated-package>.tables.USER`.

Does jOOQ have a config property to escape table names (all or just reserved keywords)? I couldn't find anything in the docs or source.

Comment: You shouldn't be using identifiers that require quoting in the first place

Comment: That's great but assumes 1) I have a choice and 2) I'm willing to sacrifice the purity of my model for a petty grammar-related reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you turned that quoting off by setting `RenderNameStyle.LOWER`... That's how it works :)

By removing that setting or by setting it to `RenderNameStyle.QUOTED`, jOOQ will generate those double quotes around all identifiers.

From the [specification](https://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-runtime-3.9.0.xsd):

```xml
<simpleType name="RenderNameStyle">
  <restriction base="string">
    <!--
     Render object names quoted, as defined in the database. Use this
     to stay on the safe side with case-sensitivity and special
     characters. For instance:
     Oracle    : "SYS"."ALL_TAB_COLS"
     MySQL     : `information_schema`.`TABLES`
     SQL Server: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] 
     -->
    <enumeration value="QUOTED"/>

    <!--
     Render object names, as defined in the database. For instance:
     Oracle    : SYS.ALL_TAB_COLS
     MySQL     : information_schema.TABLES
     SQL Server: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     -->
    <enumeration value="AS_IS"/>

    <!--
     Force rendering object names in lower case. For instance:
     Oracle    : sys.all_tab_cols
     MySQL     : information_schema.tables
     SQL Server: information_schema.tables 
     -->
    <enumeration value="LOWER"/>

    <!--
     Force rendering object names in upper case. For instance:
     Oracle    : SYS.ALL_TAB_COLS
     MySQL     : INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     SQL Server: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     -->
    <enumeration value="UPPER"/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Note, there are feature requests to add more documentation to the Javadoc ([#2830](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2830)) and the manual ([#5231](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5231))

Comment: Thanks for the spec, I missed that! I guess I was hoping there'd be a way to do both - quoting and case are orthogonal concerns after all. The bottom line is jOOQ is generating invalid SQL. Worth filing a bug do you think?

Comment: @coudy: I wouldn't bet too much money on that claim: *"quoting and case are orthogonal concerns after all"*. After all, quoting makes identifiers (in most databases) case-*sensitive* when unquoted identifiers are (in most databases) case-*insensitive*. Why do you need to lower-case your names in the first place?

Comment: @coudy: Well, there's some room for improvement, surely. We'll consider it: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5909

Comment: Point taken about non-orthogonality. I'm lower-casing because I'm invoking  the codegen on a H2 schema, which doesn't seem to preserve case. The result is then used on Postgres in prod, which cares about case. Not sure if this is a standard practice but that's how it is.

Comment: Huh, excellent example. H2 is upper-case/case-insensitive by default, whereas PostgreSQL is lower-case/case-insensitive by default. Quoting identifiers makes them case-sensitive in both databases. One way forward would be to write your H2 DDL quoted/lower-case. That way, the jOOQ code generator would pick up the casing "correctly" (i.e. as in PostgreSQL) and it would work. There are other options, but too complicated for a comment. If you ask a new question, I'll happily list a couple of alternatives.

Comment: +1. This is why I stumbled on this thread- I'm also now code-gen-ing off an H2 database and the quoting behavior is breaking in my actual SQL server.

Comment: @J.Dimeo: If you really want to use another database product to emulate your production database, then you need to be careful to have the exact same naming / case-sensitivity schemes as your production database. Better fix your test database rather than tweaking things afterwards with jOOQ. Another option is to use one of the file-based code generation solutions: [JPA](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa), [XML](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-xml), [DDL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-ddl)

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant- using H2 via a file-based DDL generator. It's working now though thanks to those settings (using AS-IS).

Comment: It's a pity that I cannot tell to quote only the keywords and reserved names, but keep other identifiers unquoted.

Comment: @HonzaZidek: It sounds useful at first, but will bite you in weird ways later. a) there's always a keyword that isn't documented, added in a later version, etc. (it would be a constant maintenance effort on a dialect version basis) b) you'll get case insensitive identifiers by default *except* for a few identifiers that you're not aware of. So, why not just quote everything if there's a need? Note tha tif you're using the code generator ([and you should!](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/)), then this isn't really a problem at all.

Comment: @LukasEder Point taken. However, "if you're using the code generator" - even then I use logs to see the SQL, because - to be honest - I am using JOOQ against my will (the company standard) :) so I prefer debugging SQL rather than the weird pseudo-Java pseudo-SQL :) So a more concise SQL is always welcomed in the logs, but then some smart developer always names a table "user" and with non-quoted names I am screwed. Quite recently I was struggling with the problem of having `List<UUID> list` and I needed to use `SELECT FROM (VALUES (id1), (id2), ... )` and the debugging was not easy.

Comment: @HonzaZidek: Not sure about the point of the comment *"against my will"*. jOOQ's quoting *everything* will guarantee things *always* work. Check out how many times there's a bug in alternative libraries that tried to do things as you suggested. They never tire of adding/removing more keywords, completely unnecessarily, if they had the same default as jOOQ. You can always render SQL differently, just for your logs, though, e.g. with an `ExecuteListener`. I'm not sure how the `UUID` example is related? Perhaps, you could ask a new question about that?

Comment: @LukasEder "Against my will": the company coding standards require it. I myself prefer R2DBC standard methods for simple SQL, and native queries for more complex ones, over any "Java-to-SQL mapping". When I talk to Java, I want to use Java, when I talk to the database I want to use its own language. Especially with all the support IntelliJ IDEA gives me to write the SQL even inside the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: @LukasEder The UUID example is related just as an illustration that I had a more complex use case which was difficult to write using jOOQ, and I needed to intensively debug the generated SQL - and with so many `"` everywhere it was less readable. However, I fully understand your point of keeping the list of reserved words up-to-date.

Comment: @HonzaZidek: I'm sorry, I don't understand how it is difficult or related to quoting of identifiers... I can probably help, but I need more context.

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks for your kind offer to help, but I eventually somehow solved it. I was even considering to share my solution for others (and to verify with you if it is optimal), but extracting a MCVE and replacing all the company proprietary code would be too much work :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek: OK, fair enough. And remember, there's no one stopping you [combining jOOQ with plain SQL (templates or raw)](https://blog.jooq.org/using-java-13-text-blocks-for-plain-sql-with-jooq/) as well as using views and table valued functions for the static part of your SQL queries, and jOOQ only for the dynamic part!