# Jooq Pro does not add square brackets in T-SQL query

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jooq

I'm using Jooq Pro in order to query a MSSQL Server database. The main issue is that the database name contains hyphens (-) as a results when I'm using for example the following:

```
dsl.select().from(table).fetch();
```

I get syntax error near "-". Please note that the table inside from() is a Table<?> object that I obtained from the `dsl.meta()`

Any ideas how to achieve this? Is there any method that I can use in order to add [] in every parameter? For example select * from [database-name].[schema-name].[tableName] ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is, in truth, one reason why using object names that require being delimit identified is a *bad* idea. Ideally, learn from this lesson.

Comment: For object names, you could create [synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) without the hyphens that you can reference without needing the quotes. However I don't think that will work for schemas or databases

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438463/how-to-make-jooq-quote-table-names-that-are-reserved-keywords

Comment: @Xedni This wall helpful yes. can you please post it as an answer to mark it for other that my need it?